A vector space must obey some rules. I need some clarification on how we check if the rules are obeyed.
I am self-studying linear algebra out of interest. I am using Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra 6th Edition. I need some clarification on a problem set, because there are some discrepancies between the solution that I came up with and the solution manual published in https://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila6/ila6sols.pdf.
The problem set is 3.1.1:
Suppose $(x_1, x_2) + (y_1, y_2)$ is defined to be $(x_1+y_2, x_2+y_1)$. With the usual multiplication $c\pmb{x}=(cx_1, cx_2)$,  which of the eight conditions are not satisfied?
For context the eight conditions are:

$\pmb{x+y = y+x}$
$\pmb{x + (y + z) = (x + y) + z}$
A zero vector exist such that $\pmb{x} +\pmb{0} = \pmb{x}$
An additive inverse, $-\pmb{x}$ exists such that $\pmb{x} + (\pmb{-x}) =0 $
The multiplication of $\pmb{x}$ with a scalar, $1$ equals $\pmb{x}$
$(c_1c_2)\pmb{x} = c_1(c_2\pmb{x})$
$c(\pmb{x} + \pmb{y}) = c\pmb{x} + c\pmb{y}$
$(c_1 + c_2)\pmb{x} = c_1\pmb{x} +c_2\pmb{x}$

From what I have tried, the conditions that are not satisfied is 1,2 and 7. But the solution manual is 1, 2 and 8.
So this is my attempt. Am I on the right track?
For condition 1:
\begin{align} &\pmb{x} = (x_1, x_2) \\ & \pmb{y} =(y_1, y_2) \end{align}
\begin{align}
\pmb{x} + \pmb{y} & = (x_1+y_2, x_2+y_1) \\
& = (y_2+x_1, y_1 + x_2) \\ 
& \neq (y_1, y_2) + (x_1, x_2)\\
& \neq \pmb{y} + \pmb{x}\end{align}
For condition 2:
\begin{align} & \pmb{x} = (x_1, x_2) \\ & \pmb{y} =(y_1, y_2) \\ & \pmb{z} = (z_1, z_2) \end{align}
\begin{align} 
\pmb{x} + (\pmb{y} + \pmb{z}) & = (x_1, x_2) + (y_1+z_1, y_2+z_2) \\
& = (x_1 + y_1 + z_1, x_2 + y_2 + z_2) \\
& = (x_1 + y_1, x_2 +y_2) + (z_1, z_2) \\
& \neq (x_1 + y_2, x_2 + y_1) + (z_1, z_2) \\
& \neq (\pmb{x} + \pmb{y}) + \pmb{z}
\end{align}
For condition 7:
\begin{align}
c(\pmb{x} + \pmb{y}) & = c(x_1 + y_2, x_2 + y_1)\\
& = c(x_1, x_2) + c(y_2, y_1) \\
& \neq c\pmb{x} + c\pmb{y}
\end{align}
$ \pmb{x+y\neq y+x}$ and $ \pmb{x+(y+z)\neq(x+y)+z} $ and $ (c_1 +c_2)\pmb{x} \neq c_1\pmb{x}+c_2\pmb{x} $ : this is the solution from the solution's manual; condition 1, 2 and 8 are not satisfied, respectively.
I tried to check the eighth rule, but my attempt showed that the condition is satisfied.
For condition 8:
\begin{align}
(c_1 + c_2)\pmb{x} & = (c_1 + c_2)(x_1, x_2) \\
& = c_1(x_1, x_2) + c_2(x_1, x_2) \\
& = c_1\pmb{x} + c_2\pmb{x}
\end{align}
I am just a bit confused. There are other resources like in Chegg, and chatgpt that agree with the solution manual. I just want to know how the conclusion is reached, I feel like I understand something, but wrongly. Thank you in advance.

Good work for the most part.  Not entirely sure what part you are asking about...I just posted an argument to show that $#8$ fails, was that your primary question? I added to give an argument showing that $#7$ does hold.

In my opinion (and I do mean opinion) it is not obvious to me why $(y_2+x_1,y_1 + x_2)\ne (y_1,y_2)+(x_1,x_2)$ and why do you say $(y_1,y_2)+(x_1,x_2) \ne y+x$ when it clearly does (as $(y_1,y_2)=y$ and $(x_1,x_2)=x$).  Proving $A \ne B$ and $B \ne C$ does not prove $A\ne C$... I would have not worried about a single equation proof be noted $x+y=(x_1 + y_2,x_2 + y_1)$ while $y+x=(y_1+x_2,y_2+x_1)$ which need not equal.  If I did do it a single line I'd do $x+y=(x_1+y_2,x_2+y_1)\ne(y_1+x_2,y_2+x_1)=y+x$.

Peeve: it is not necessarily the case that, using the given definition,
$$(y_1,y_2)+(x_1,x_2) \neq (y_2+x_1,y_1+x_2)$$
as you assert in your work related to condition 1. That is, this statement, as written, is not accurate. Rather, equality is not guaranteed, but could happen (for example, if $ x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$).
So the correct way to show equality need not hold is to provide a specific example where the equality fails to hold.
Because it is possible for two expressions to look different, but to always evaluate to the same thing (e.g., $\sin(x+\pi/2)$ is a different expression from $\cos(x)$, but they always take the same value).
So the way to finish off the verification that property 1 does not hold is to give a (counter)-example: specific values of $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, and $y_2$ for which the required equality does not in fact hold.
(Also, you falsely write that "$(y_1,y_2)+(x_1,x_2)\neq \mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}$"; in fact, they are equal).
The same is true for every one of the conditions you claim do not hold for this example.

and along the same lines, another peeve of mine is the use of $\neq$ sign twice (since it isn’t a transitive relation). This is a bad habit OP should stop immediately

@peek-a-boo In this case, it is actually false in its second instance, as I mention in the penultimate paragraph.

@ArturoMagidin thank you for pointing it out. I just realised what I did was wrong. Can you show what you mean by providing a verification via a counter-example?

@FatSalami What you did is incomplete. The calculation you do gives you an idea of why it might be the case that the operation is not commutative: because in general you cannot expect $x_1+y_2$ to be the same as $y_1+x_2$, nor $x_2+y_1$ to be the same as $y_2+x_1$. That suggests how to find specific, explicit numbers that will actually show that they need not be equal.

For the left hand (of condition $\#8$):
$$(c_1+c_2)(x_1,x_2)=((c_1+c_2)x_1,(c_1+c_2)x_2)$$
For the right hand:
$$c_1(x_1,x_2)+c_2(x_1,x_2)=(c_1x_1,c_1x_2)+(c_2x_1,c_2x_2)$$
$$\quad \quad =(c_1x_1+c_2x_2,c_2x_1+c_1x_2)$$
From which it is easy to see the difference.
There is no problem with $\#7$:
For $\#7$ the left hand is:  $$c((x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2))=c(x_1+y_2,x_2+y_1)=(c(x_1+y_2),c(x_2+y_1))$$
While the right hand is:  $$(cx_1,cx_2)+(cy_1,cy_2)=(cx_1+cy_2,cy_1+cx_2)$$  and equality follows from the distributive law for real addition.

For condition #7, you switched back in the middle to the standard definition of vector addition, which is why you obtained inequality. If you leave out the c, you would also have obtained $\pmb{x+y}\neq \pmb{x+y}$.
